Flutter Azure Pipeline: "Flutter failed with exit code 1" during Android release build
I’m trying to build a release version of my Flutter app (app bundle) using an Azure DevOps pipeline. The pipeline consistently fails during the Flutter build step with the following error:
Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/3.27.0/linux/flutter/bin/flutter' failed with exit code 1

However, when I run the same flutter build appbundle --release command locally, the build succeeds without any issues.
Here is the relevant portion of my pipeline YAML for the Android stage:
- stage: AndroidStage
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    displayName: Android
    jobs:
      - job: AndroidJob
        displayName: Build Android App
        steps:
          - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
            name: keyprop
            displayName: Download key properties file
            inputs:
              secureFile: 'app_props.properties'

          - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
            name: key
            displayName: Download store file
            inputs:
              secureFile: 'app_keystore.jks'

          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Copy config files
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                cp $(keyprop.secureFilePath) $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/android
                cp $(key.secureFilePath) $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/android/app
                chmod +x $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/android/gradlew

          - task: FlutterInstall@0
            displayName: 'Install Flutter SDK'
            inputs:
              mode: 'auto'
              channel: 'stable'
              version: 'custom'
              customVersion: '3.27.0'

          - task: FlutterCommand@0
            displayName: 'Get Flutter Packages'
            inputs:
              arguments: 'pub get'

          - task: FlutterBuild@0
            displayName: 'Build application'
            inputs:
              target: 'aab'
              projectDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
              arguments: '--verbose'

          - task: CopyFiles@2
            displayName: 'Copy app to staging directory'
            inputs:
              sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build/app/outputs/bundle/release'
              contents: '*.aab'
              targetFolder: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)'

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: 'Publish AAB file'
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)'
              ArtifactName: 'android'
              publishLocation: 'Container'


I'm afraid that's not a very helpful error message. Have you tried running the pipeline in debug mode? Are there any more details?
